# Error while I am compiling the contract using node

Tags: solidity, nodejs

> ```
> saitejas-MacBook-Air:Inbox saitejakuruva$ sudo node compile.js assert.js:340
> throw err;
> ^
> ```
>
> AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Invalid callback specified.
>       at wrapCallback (/Users/saitejakuruva/node_modules/solc/wrapper.js:16:5)
>       at runWithReadCallback (/Users/saitejakuruva/node_modules/solc/wrapper.js:42:26)
>       at compileStandard (/Users/saitejakuruva/node_modules/solc/wrapper.js:83:14)
>       at Object.compileStandardWrapper (/Users/saitejakuruva/node_modules/solc/wrapper.js:90:14)
>       at Object. (/Users/saitejakuruva/Documents/Inbox/compile.js:6:18)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:799:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:810:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:606:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:3)

I have faced the above error when I am trying to compile a simple solidity contract.I am also providing the link of the code that I have written for compiling the contract.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAxMy.png
Please help me out asap.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the second parameter of `solc.compile` here:

```js
console.log(solc.compile(source,1));
```

The second parameter should be a function or should be omitted.  If your smart contract source file does not import other source files, try removing the second parameter like this:

```js
console.log(solc.compile(source));
```

See [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js#high-level-api) for details.

Comment: But it's just saying that I have only 1 contract in my contracts directory that have to be compiled .

Comment: Check documentation.  Second parameter may not be a number, it should either be a function or should be omitted.